# Controller#Create - Couldn't find User with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I'm learning web-dev and rails and have been stuck for a couple days on this.

I have two models - `User` and `Property` and have set-up associations I think correctly.

What I'm trying to do is only allow a `property` to be created if a `user` is signed in and to have that `property` belonging to that `user`.  The sign in part I got, but when I go to create the property, it gives me the `"Couldn't find User..."` error.

I used a `DB SQL Browser` to verify that there is a user and that there is a user ID, so don't understand why it can't find it when signed in.

Appreciate any help.

---

Controller:

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController

before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new]

def index
    @properties = Property.all
end

def new 
    @property = Property.new
end

def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @property = @user.properties.new(property_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @property.save
        format.html { redirect_to @property, notice: 'Property was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, location: @property}
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json 
      end
    end
end

def show
    @property = Property.find(params[:id])
end

def edit

end

def update

end

def destroy

end

private

def property_params
        params.require(:property).permit(:street, :city, :province, :postal_code, :description, :picture)
end
end
```

Database:

```
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160204211556) do

  create_table "properties", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "street"
t.string   "city"
t.string   "province"
t.string   "postal_code"
t.text     "description"
t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
t.integer  "property_id"
t.string   "picture"
t.integer  "user_id"
end

add_index "properties", ["property_id"], name: "index_properties_on_property_id", unique: true
add_index "properties", ["user_id"], name: "index_properties_on_user_id"

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.string   "email"
t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
t.string   "password_digest"
t.string   "remember_digest"
t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
end

add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Models:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy 
mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

has_many :properties

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :properties # -> url.com/properties/new

#app/controllers/properties_controller.rb
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user! #-> assuming you're using devise

  def new
    @property = current_user.properties.new
  end

  def create
    @property = current_user.properties.new property_params
    respond_to do |format|
      if @property.save
        format.html { redirect_to @property, notice: 'Property was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, location: @property}
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json 
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def property_params
     params.require(:property).permit(:street, :city, :province, :postal_code, :description)
  end
end

#app/views/properties/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @property do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :street %>
   <%= f.text_field :city %>
   <%= f.text_field :province %>
   <%= f.text_field :postal_code %>
   <%= f.text_field :description %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will create a new property for the [`current_user`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) (assuming you're using [`Devise`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication)

Comment: Thanks Rick.  Edited one part in creates to get around another error but conceptually everything you provided put me in the right direction.  Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you can provide your `routes.rb` and error messages.

My guess is, since you are doing `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])` in your properties controller, your user_id is not present in the params so rails cannot find the user_id.

In your `routes.rb`, you may need

```
resources :users do 
   resources :properties
end
```

so that the link would become something like `localhost:3000/users/1/properties/new` and rails can find the user_id.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

```
@user = User.new(user_permit)
```

on your **def create**

Then add this to the bottom of your controller

```
private
def user_permit
    params[:user].permit!
end
```